# ajax - How can I build a chat with Ajax and settimeout without the process taking a lot of virtual memory?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to build a chat based on AJAX that receives data every second by settimeout.
I wrote a basic code where there is a number that increases each second of the number obtained from the php page2.
I checked it from my computer by opening the file in 3 different browsers and saw that it takes a lot of virtual memory from the server. My fear is what will happen if I build a real chat in this format and 50 people simultaneously enter?
I know that setTimeout takes a lot of memory, is there any other way to build chat? Or can I improve what I did?
I would be very happy to answer!

that's what i did:

```
<body>
<h1 id='number'>0</h1>

<script>
function ajax() {
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  var a = new XMLHttpRequest()
 } else {
  var a = new ActivXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
 }
 return a
}

var settime = 1000;
var myTime;

ajaxMain();

function ajaxMain() {
 xmlhttp = ajax();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) || (xmlhttp.readyState == 0)) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
   if (xmlhttp.responseText) {
    id('mmm').innerHTML = (xmlhttp.responseText) * 1 + (id('number').innerHTML) * 1;
    myTime = setTimeout('ajaxMain()', settime)
   }
  } else {
   if (xmlhttp.responseText.match(/^\<\!/)) {
    clearTimeout(myTime);
    myTime = setTimeout('ajaxMain()', settime)
   }
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.open('GET', 'page2.php', true)
 xmlhttp.send()
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.php:

```
<?php

echo 1
?>
```

Comment: Some proper code indention would make it easier to read and follow the code.

Comment: I would suggest looking in to using sockets instead, if you want to build a proper chat.

Comment: i wrote my code above. it's a basic ajax and settimeout that's gets every minit a number and adds it to the number befor

Comment: I didn't ask for code, I asked you to format/indent the code to make it more readable. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thier is a full guide how to create an AJAX based chat system in PHP by Ashraf Gheith,
I'll quote:

```
 CREATE TABLE `chat` (
`id` INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`usrname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
`color` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL , 
`chattext` TEXT NOT NULL , 
`chattime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
 ) ENGINE = MyISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

```js
var lastTimeID = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSend').click( function() {
    sendChatText();
    $('#chatInput').val("");
  });
  startChat();
});

function startChat(){
  setInterval( function() { getChatText(); }, 2000);
}

function getChatText() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/refresh.php?lastTimeID=" + lastTimeID
  }).done( function( data )
  {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    var jsonLength = jsonData.results.length;
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
      var result = jsonData.results[i];
      html += '<div style="color:#' + result.color + '">(' + result.chattime + ') <b>' + result.usrname +'</b>: ' + result.chattext + '</div>';
      lastTimeID = result.id;
    }
    $('#view_ajax').append(html);
  });
}

function sendChatText(){
  var chatInput = $('#chatInput').val();
  if(chatInput != ""){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/submit.php?chattext=" + encodeURIComponent( chatInput )
    });
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#view_ajax {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px; 
  height: 300px; 
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#ajaxForm{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px; 
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#chatInput{
  width: 454px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chat Room Example</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="view_ajax"></div>
    <div id="ajaxForm">
      <input type="text" id="chatInput" /><input type="button" value="Send" id="btnSend" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The full guide will be on this [link](https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/3213/post/1-Tutorial-on-Creating-an-AJAX-based-Chat-system-in-PHP.html)